# Error information about node and npm when launching terminal on Mac

Tags: node.js, npm

Every time I launch my terminal on my mac, I will receive the following error information:

```
ERROR: npm is known not to run on Node.js v11.0.0
You'll need to upgrade to a newer Node.js version in order to use this
version of npm. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""
Run `npm config delete prefix` or `nvm use --delete-prefix v11.0.0 --silent` to unset it.
```

However,

```
node -v   
v16.15.1  
npm -v  
8.11.0
```

So how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't really familiar with Mac but I think that you should uninstall any version of Nodejs on your Mac that are installed and reinstall it from [Nodejs Download Page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) using the .pkg file.

Comment: Thanks! I solve this issue by resetting the terminal, and I also reinstalled it.